# Create a variable of certain type in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to create variable in my component of certain type like below.

```
myrequest.model.ts
export class MyRequest {
    public endValue: string;
    public yearEnd: string;
}
```

In my component i import the above and do like below

```
myReqObj: MyRequest;
```

But if i try to do like

```
this.myReqObj.endValue = '23'
```

it trows a error like myReqObj is undefined. Am i doing the right way? What is the right way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be defining the value as

```
this.myReqObj ={
      endValue : '23'
}
```

Updated : Use interface for custom types like these.

```
export interface MyRequest {
    endValue: string;
    yearEnd: string;
}
```

Comment: Am i doing the things in right manner i.e. creating a class and trying to create a variable of that type or should i create a interface? Am following best practice?

Comment: you should be using the best practice `(using interface)`

Comment: Just a question. Why it should not a class?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you need to instantiate MyRequest.
If you add a constructor, you can do this:

```
myReqObj: MyRequest = new MyRequest(null, null);
this.myReqObj.endValue = '23'
```